# Can I configure a maximum number of open popovers with React antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd, popover

I'd like to use a React component to specify a maximum number of popovers open simultaneously on my pages. The aim is, for example, to be able to say that I want 2 popovers open simultaneously. When the user opens a new popover, one of the old popovers must close.

Do you know if something like this already exists?

I'm waiting to see what already exists before thinking of a custom solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.